# Merging two large pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dask

I am trying to merge two dataframes with common id. I have tried dask, merge, pandas. Still am getting the memory error.
Size of one dataframe is 120 mb and another one is 198 mb.
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Please provide a minimum verifiable example of code and the stacktrace for the error.

Comment: Take a look at how here: [mcve]

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem merging two dfs of that size in Pandas if you're doing the right type of join. By doing an appropriate inner join you shouldn't end up with a df larger than the combined size of the initial two. Other types of joins will end up doing combinatorics and getting you enormous results. Try with a very small subset of each dataframe to verify your join is working correctly before trying on the full data sets.

Comment: I have used inner join on one paramater. Also i have tried using a sample of the whole data. It then worked fine. But when am dealing with the whole df, it's giving memory error. I have reduced the size of df by converting into suitable data type also. I have used dask in the end. But still that's taking way more time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was making some mistake in using pandas.merge only.